# [Swift, Alamofire]: responseValidationFailed with error code 400

Tags: swift, post, instagram, alamofire

My problem is basically in the title. The code that I am trying to run is just below. VVV

```
let unfollow = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/\(userID)/relationship?access_token=\(access_token)&action=unfollow"

    Alamofire.request(unfollow, method: .post).validate().responseJSON(completionHandler: {
        response in

        switch response.result {

        case .success(let value):

            let data = JSON(value)["data"]
            print(data["outgoing_status"].stringValue)

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)

        }

    })
```

The exact console error I recieve is: `responseValidationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseValidationFailureReason.unacceptableStatusCode(400))`

I am using the Instagram API by the way but I don't think that that is necessarily related to the issue.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you check value of `unfollow` variable and add it to the post. I'm suspecting you have bunch of `Optional(…)` in the string.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The erro log responseValidationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseValidationFailureReason.unacceptableStatusCode(400)) clearly shows that you are getting 400 error. Which is explained in [W3.org](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1) as

> 400 Bad Request:
>   The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.

So you need to chek you request URL if it is correct.

Also, you are using validate() method of request which is supposed to get response status codes 200...299, but you are getting 400 as response code. Thats why it is mentioned as unacceptableStatusCode(400) in error log.

Seel [this](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1659) also.